# formview change to edit mode programmatically

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have a formView and bind these events:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div dir="ltr">
        <table>
            <tr>

                <td class="titleHead">Categury:</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lst"  Text='<%#  Eval("ItemCat.Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="titleHead">Name :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>

             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'  Width="300px" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>


            <tr> 
                <td class="titleHead">Description :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtDescription"  Text='<%#  Eval("Description") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 150px;">

**<asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit"   ImageUrl="~" CommandName="Edit" runat="server"  />**
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" ImageUrl="~" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" />

                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>


            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>
</ItemTemplate>   
<EditItemTemplate>
    <div dir="ltr">

        <table>
             <tr>

                <td class="style1">Categury:</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>   

             </tr>
             <tr>

                <td>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstCats" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name"  ValidationGroup="vgrpEditfrm" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>

             </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>Name :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>


             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text=""  Width="300px" ValidationGroup="vgrpEditfrm" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                     </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqValidator" ControlToValidate="txtName" ForeColor="Red" 
                         ValidationGroup="vgrpEditfrm" runat="server">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>      </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>Display Name :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td> 

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                     <cke:CKEditorControl ID="txtDisplayName" Text=""  Toolbar="Source |Bold|Italic|Underline|Strike|SpecialChar|-|JustifyLeft|JustifyCenter|JustifyRight|JustifyBlock|BidiLtr|BidiRtl|-|Subscript|Superscript|NumberedList|BulletedList|-|Outdent|Indent/Styles|Format|Font|FontSize|TextColor|BGColor|Link|" Height="40px" BasePath="~/Resource/ckeditor" ValidationGroup="vgrpEditfrm" runat="server"></cke:CKEditorControl>

                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                      </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Descritpion :</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>  

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                      <cke:CKEditorControl ID="txtDescription" Text=""    Toolbar="Full"  BasePath="~/Resource/ckeditor" Height="1000px" ValidationGroup="vgrpEditfrm" runat="server" />

                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 150px;">
                  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="" CausesValidation="true"   ValidationGroup="vgrpEditfrm"  runat="server" />
                  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="" ValidationGroup="vgrpEditfrm" runat="server" />

                   </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>


</EditItemTemplate>
```

And:

```
void frm_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text += "changing...";
        //here my currunrformviw state  is readonly
        Frm.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
         //now mode is Edit
    }

void frm_ModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // this method doesn't raised and FormView is In Readonly Mode
        lblResult.Text += "changed...";

    }
```

when I click Edit Button changing raised but changed not rasid

**Update**:
Actually I want when click editbutton in readonly mode, it goes to Edit Mode.

Comment: Surely you should be changing the mode inside the button click event. You cannot change the mode inside the changing event which is what your code above is showing.

Comment: Dear @CraigMoore tnx, i call it in ItemCommand but it doesn't work :(, I hate asp.net controls, so now deceide using raw html and binding by ajax and jquery

Comment: When you call it in ItemCommand you are removing the call from inside fem_ModeChanging, yes?

Comment: in other word, i change itemName to "GoEdit" and Check it in itemCOmmand Event and call formviewChangemode method. but it doesn't work yet